# Why is my C# class name defaulted to Class1?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, class

This is going to sound stupid, and I apologize beforehand. I come from Java and NetBeans IDE, and this is the first time I've used C# and Visual Studio.

My question is - why does Visual Studio name my class `Class1` by default?

Here are my steps for creating a new project.

[image]

In the New Project page, nowhere does it say `Class1`.

When the new project gets created, my empty page says `Class1` everywhere.

[image]

What is going on here? Is there a way to change the behavior of this to match the name I give my project? So instead of `Class1`it would say like `SimpleMathematics` instead.

Sorry if this is a dumb question.

Comment: so what is the better name for default new class? If allows you to rename at the open dialog, why don't you use that feature?

Comment: Why would you name your class the same as your namespace? Also project is not the same as class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A project usually contains many classes, that is the **default behvaiour of  Visual Studio**, you can always rename the `Class1.cs` file and it will allow you to change the name of the class in code.

You can also delete the `Class1.cs` file and add your new one.

Comment: Pardon me - but where do I change the name? Is it possible to do this in `New Project`?

Comment: @theGreenCabbage, right click on the `Class1.cs` in Solution explorer and rename it

Comment: Or click F2 on the file and rename the .cs.  I honestly delete the first class and create new. The "Class1" is only a dummy class to give  an example on how to do it.

Comment: By default, when you create a new library project in VS, it adds a class for you with the default naming schema.

Answer (score 2):

The default name of the files and classes are set within VS templates.

You can go to C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\Code\1033\Class.zip

Extract the files and there you will find the file Class.cs with the following code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
$if$ ($targetframeworkversion$ >= 3.5)using System.Linq;
$endif$using System.Text;

namespace $rootnamespace$
{
    class $safeitemrootname$
    {
    }

}
```

You can change this template to get the name you need everytime you create a class.

Answer (score 0):

You can always right click on "Class1" and choose Refactor -> Rename from the context menu to rename it to something else.

Comment: Thanks! Are there any specific naming dos and don'ts? I know in Java the name of the project and the name of the class remains the same, while in C# it's different.

Comment: I'm pretty sure Refactor come with Resharper. Not with visual studio

Comment: @skatanick, Refactor is available with Visual studio *(although limited)*, just right click on the class name in code and select refactor

Comment: @Habib I know how, it's just that resharper is always installed on my pc :). and I didn't remember having refactor before but thx for the info.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are creating a class library, which is a 'collection' of a bunch of different classes. Since you're not directly creating a class, Visual Studio inserts a new one for you, and names it Class1.

Answer (score 0):

What I do when I want to rename an existing class. I first right click the class in the explorer and select rename. I then open the class and highlight the class name at the top - right click and refactor to the new name.